# How can I take input of a select class and print is somewhere?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a dropdown menu as a select class and I want to print the selection that I choose from the dropdown, what should I do ?

```
<div>
<select class = "selection">
<option value=""> selection1 </option>
<option value=""> selection1 </option>
<option value=""> selection1 </option>
<option value=""> selection1 </option>
</select>
<div>
```

Print in vue:

{{ session.user.selection }}

I have multiple user picking different selections

Comment: Consider using [form input bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html). It's well documented.